# Passing 2d char array using string literal without initialization in c

Tags: arrays, c, char, 2d

With 1d char array you could pass them as string literal like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void go(char *a)
{
  printf("%s", a);
}

int main() 
{
  go("Hello");
  
  return 0;
}
```

But can we do this with 2d char array ? something like this perhaps

```
void go (int rowSize, int colSize, char a[rowSize][colSize])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n"), a[i]);
  }
}

go(2, 16, {"Hello", "Hi"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use compound literal:

```
void go (size_t rowSize, size_t colSize, char a[rowSize][colSize])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    go(2, 16, (char[][16]){"Hello", "Hi"});
  
    return 0;
}
```

As @Lundin suggested you can also use an array of pointers:

```
void go (size_t nstrings, char **strings)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nstrings; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
  }
}

int main() 
{
    go(2, (char *[]){"Hello", "Hi"});
  
  return 0;
}
```

or more `const` correct version:

```
void go (int nstrings, char *const *strings)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < nstrings; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
  }
}

int main() 
{
    go(2, (char *const[]){"Hello", "Hi"});
  
  return 0;
}
```

For sizes, indexes etc is better to use `size_t` or `ssize_t`.

Comment: In this case it might make more sense to use a `char* []` array and const qualify it. Depends on what the intention is.

Comment: @Lundin IMO he simply wanted to know how to pass the 2D array without the need of creating a temporary variable. Nothing about constantness.

Comment: I'll post the alternative version for completeness.

Comment: Could you tell me why with indexes its better to use size_t or ssize_t ?

Comment: And a follow up question when one should use size_t or ssize_t ?

Comment: `char *const[]` is (hint: read right-to-left) an array of const pointers to char. It is not const correct (that would be `const char**`, pointer-to-pointer to read-only char) and the only reason why you'd want to do something like this is in case you have reason to think your compound literal ends up in RAM rather than flash on an embedded system. `*const` allocates pointer tables in flash, which is about the only use for that notation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array pointing at read-only string literals, it has to be an array of character pointers, `char* array[] = {"Hello", "Hi"};`. This type is a completely different one than a 2D array of characters and they aren't compatible.

Which form to use in this case depends on what you want to do. Should these be read/write strings or read-only? Do you plan to resize individual strings? And so on. String literals are always read only so the correct pointer type to use when pointing at them is `const char*`. However, if you only use string literals for the purpose of initializing a read/write 2D array, then that doesn't matter.

Assuming that the use case is just to print a bunch of string literals in a function and nothing else, then the most correct form is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void go(size_t n, const char* a[n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        puts(a[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    go(2, (const char*[]){"Hello", "Hi"});
}
```

This is functionally almost identical to the 2D array version, but it likely doesn't use any temporary memory for storing the strings, so you save some 2x16 bytes etc (which isn't a big deal).

Comment: Though on resource-constrained embedded systems, you probably don't want to temporarily read the string literals from flash just drop them in temporary RAM on the stack.

Comment: `const char*[]` it does not create the array of pointers to const data only the array of const pointers to non const data.

Comment: @0___________ No, you got that backwards. And in this case it shouldn't matter if the pointers are qualified or not since they will get optimized out. Disassembling on x86, gcc loads the string literal addresses directly into the stack frame used by the function, with no middle man. In the 2D array instance version it does some extra stack shovelling around (which actually surprises me). https://godbolt.org/z/7oMhraYed, see the disassembly for main().